# XSLT writing for XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having below XML document

```xml
<extensionElements> 
  <pre>
    <preEvent exp="5" src="title" dataType="string" />
    <preEvent exp="3" src="value" dataType="int" />
    <preEvent exp="1" src="reason" dataType="string" />
  </pre>
  <post>
    <postEvent exp="15" dest="title" dataType="string" />
    <postEvent exp="13" dest="value" dataType="int" />
    <postEvent exp="11" dest="reason" dataType="string" />
  </post>
</extensionElements>
```

And using above xml, I want to write XSLT template. so that my final
output will be like

```xml
<data id="a">
  <dataitem datatype="string" name="reason" source="1" target="11" />
  <dataitem datatype="int" name="value" source="3" target="13" />
  <dataitem datatype="string" name="title" source="5" target="15" />
</data>
```

Comment: What did you tried? Add a [mcve].

Comment: @ceving Please do not edit OP's code - you don't know what it looks like.

Comment: @HIMANSHU JAIN An example is not enough; please explain the required logic in words.